# show specific feed related to entry; however, a single page template is being used

Tags: rss

I have a single page template that is used to show a specific entry (based on url segment). When the unique page content is displayed, I would like to show a specific unique feed also.

I'm thinking i can have a custom field in the entry screen where I enter the unique feed url. Then use either use EE native feed functionality or Andrew Weaver's RSS plugin to display the feed.

However, I'm not sure if is it possible to call the custom field that holds the url?

Any ideas or other ways to solve this problem?

thanks

> {exp:ajw_feedparser 
>      url="??????"
>      cache_refresh="60"
>      limit="8"
>   }
>
> {title}
>
> {description}
>
> {/exp:ajw_feedparser}

Answer (score 1):

Sounds reasonable, add a new `text` field to the channel named 'feed URL' make sure the field is set to formatting: none.

Then in you channel loop:

```
{exp:channel:entries url_title="{segment_x}"}

  ... {channel data} ...

  {exp:ajw_feedparser url="{feed_url}" cache_refresh="60" limit="8" }
    {title}
    {description}
  {/exp:ajw_feedparser}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```